# How to write new columns inside appendRow() in Google Sheets script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I am a newbie and new to Google Web App form - Spreadsheet integration. I have a dummy form that i want create and write it to my Spreadsheet.

This is what my form looks like:

[image: Filled form]

And if i submit it, i wanna write it to the Spreadsheet like this:

[image: Spreadsheet after submitted]

But if I use `appendRow()`:

```
sheet.appendRow([formObject.name, formObject.idnum, formObject.things1, formObject.things2, formObject.things3]);
```

It would show like this:

[image: Spreadsheet 1]

And if i write:

```
sheet.appendRow([formObject.name]);
sheet.appendRow([formObject.idnum]);
sheet.appendRow([formObject.things1]);
sheet.appendRow([formObject.things2]);
sheet.appendRow([formObject.things3]);
```

It would result like this:

[image: Spreadsheet 2]

I tried this:

```
sheet.appendRow([formObject.name,formObject.idnum, formObject.things1,formObject.freq1]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things2]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null ,formObject.things3]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null,formObject.things4]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null,formObject.things5]);

sheet.appendRow([null, null, null, formObject.freq2]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null, null, formObject.freq3]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null, null, formObject.freq4]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null, null, formObject.freq5]);
```

And this is the result:

[image: Spreadsheet 3]

Then how could I write a new column inside `appendRow()`?

Comment: This line `sheet.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things2]);` says Fill Last row: col 1 with null, col2 with null, col3 with things. Do you understand that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append with empty spaces/null prefilled:

```
sheet.appendRow([formObject.name, formObject.idnum, formObject.things1]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things2]);
sheet.appendRow([null, null, formObject.things3]);
```

Alternatively, use [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues), which accepts a 2D array:

```
range.setValues([
    [formObject.name, fortmObject.idnum],
    [null, null, formObject.things1],
    [null, null, formObject.things2t],
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the respond. I've tried the null before but it ended up make the cells above things1 is empty. And it also does the same thing for the next column ('Frequency' field).

Comment: @Ray Put things1 in the first line then